# Difference between sysproc.c and proc.c

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls, scheduling, xv6

I’m doing a project for class that includes implementing a lottery scheduler in xv6. I have to implement two system calls `settickets()` and `getpinfo()`. I added the system calls to `syscall.c`, `syscall.h`, `sysfile.c`, `user.h`, `usys.S` etc.

I’m confused about where I put the actual code to implement the system calls. Some sites say the code goes in `sysproc.c` and others say `proc.c` . Can it go in either and what is the difference between the two files? also would the name be `int sys_settickets()` or just `int settickets()` ?

(what i mean by implementation; idk if that word is correct in this context)

```
int sys_settickets() 
{
 //code 
}
```

or

```
int settickets() 
{
//code
}
```